# How would I resolve this 422 error during POST?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to follow a code along on Udemy except making my version of the project. After using bcrypt and jwt, I'm unable to make any posts to my app. I'm able to login fine, but when trying to post something, I get a 422 error.

This is what's getting me stuck.

```
  const twottSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("title", formState.inputs.title.value);
      formData.append("description", formState.inputs.description.value);
      formData.append("creator", auth.userId);
      await sendRequest("http://localhost:3001/api/twotts", "POST", formData, {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token,
      });
      history.push("/");
    } catch (err) {}
  };
```

In the twotts-controller, this is what's throwing the error,

```
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(new HttpError("Invalid input passed", 422));
  }
  const { title, description, creator } = req.body;
  const createdTwott = new Twott({
    title,
    description,
    creator,
  });
```

Is there a way to make it so it adds it using JSON.stringify instead of using FormData? Using

```
    try {
      await sendRequest(
        "http://localhost:3001/api/twotts",
        "POST",
        JSON.stringify({
          title: formState.inputs.title.value,
          description: formState.inputs.description.value,
          creator: auth.userId,
        }),
        { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token },
        { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      );
      history.push("/");
    } catch (err) {}
```

I still get invalid inputs. If I put the Authorization argument anywhere else, I'd get authentication issues.

the link to the repo is https://github.com/preintercede/Twotter (with commits) in case there's a part that I missed.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(req.body)` before validation, and check what is inside req.body?

Comment: Apparently nothing is getting passed as it returns an empty object. It was working before, but not sure why it isnt anymore.

Comment: Hm, better yet, since I'm not planning on using images, is it possible to use JSON. stringify to add the twott instead of using a form? I'll update my post to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing `FormData` and send it (implicitly) with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. `express-validator` doesn't validate such data out-of-the box (reasoning: https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/276)

One solution would be to use https://github.com/expressjs/multer, but my recommendation is just to submit JSON data with correct `Content-Type`, as already you're doing for other requests:

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 modified: src/twotts/pages/NewTwott.js
 ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 @ src/twotts/pages/NewTwott.js:39 @ const NewTwott = () => {
      event.preventDefault();

      try {
 -      const formData = new FormData();
 -      formData.append("title", formState.inputs.title.value);
 -      formData.append("description", formState.inputs.description.value);
 -      formData.append("creator", auth.userId);
 -      await sendRequest("http://localhost:3001/api/twotts", "POST", formData, {
 +      await sendRequest("http://localhost:3001/api/twotts", "POST", JSON.stringify({
 +        title: formState.inputs.title.value,
 +        description: formState.inputs.description.value,
 +        creator: auth.userId
 +      }), {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token,
 +        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        });
        history.push("/");
      } catch (err) {}
```

I recommend to wrap this into a helper function. This could also set the Bearer token to the request headers if present.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking something like  that, but I must've misplaced on where to put the Authorization. Thanks!

Comment: You have a security flaw in your https://github.com/preintercede/Twotter/blob/master/controllers/twotts-controllers.js  for example in `createTwott`: you must not take the `userId` from request payload, but from verified JWT token. With current code, an authenticated user could post (in this example) as any other user, if the user id is known. Fortunately, `check-auth.js` middleware already checks and appends the userId to the request.